# Calls to Admin API not counting towards 20 successful calls for Go Live

Tags: docusignapi

I have written a small DocuSign integration using the [Admin API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/admin-api/) that enables DocuSign account provisioning and de-provisioning through our in-house automation platform. The app uses the JWT OAuth flow for authentication.

The integration works fine, I can list users, list groups and permission profiles, create users, and remove users.

But none of those successful calls show up in the API Dashboard, so I can't submit my app for the Go Live process. I've tried a few times over several weeks, so this is not an issue with a delay - they just never show up.

I tried a quick-start project that uses the eSign API, and those calls do show up. Why don't my Admin API calls show up?

[Edit: I'm impersonating the same user in the API call that I log in to the Dashboard with... I know the Dashboard only shows calls made by the person viewing it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, only eSignature API calls count towards the automated Go-Live. You can perform 20 eSignature API calls and use that to go live or reach out to DocuSign support for a manual review